# update dynamically created textbox in c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox

i have asp.net web application in which i used to generate list of text boxes depend on count in table and generate button at the end of column dynamically to update value in text boxes.I have attached sample code for reference for example purpose i have assign
**c** limit to **5** how i can update this textbox controls at dynamically generated button click event.

Sample Code:

```
TableRow rowpoint = new TableRow();
                    TableCell cellpoint = new TableCell();
                    cellpoint.Text = "Total Points";
                    rowpoint.Cells.Add(cellpoint);

                    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                    {

                        TableCell cellinput = new TableCell();
                        TextBox txtinput = new TextBox();

                        cellinput.Controls.Add(txtinput);
                        rowpoint.Cells.Add(cellinput);
                    }


                    TableCell totpoint = new TableCell();

                    totpoint.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(221, 221, 221);

                    Button btnupdate2 = new Button();
                    btnupdate2.Text = "Update";
                    totpoint.Controls.Add(btnupdate2);
                    rowpoint.Cells.Add(totpoint);
                    tbl1.Rows.Add(rowpoint);
                    //End Adding Total Points
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a unique id to each textbox while creating the textboxes. Add a button click handler while creating the button

```
btnupdate2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnupdate2_OnClick)
```

Then write the below event handler

```
protected void btnupdate2_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {


}
```

Inside this use FindControl to get each textbox.

Comment: hi praveen
when I give unique id to textbox and build application it automatically attach 'ctl00$contentpanel' to my textbox id.so how i can get exact id of textbox

Comment: While using the FindControl you need to give only the ID you gave.

Ex: If you set like txtinput.ID="id1";

then you can use ((Textbox)FindControl("id1")) to get the textbox runtime. Mapping it to a valid unique identifier (with prefix) will be done automatically.

Comment: i try as you have said, but it give me error like this **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**.I also try to count control in my form using this **this.Form.Controls.Count**  it gave me count 3,as my form contains many controls.I think it may be because of i am using web content form inherited from master form so it's counting controls on this master form.what say...

Comment: Find control will not look recursively.